# Phonegap app crashes after asking for location permission

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

When the App doesn't have permission for location and I open it, it asks for permission and after I gave it permission it crashes. If it has permission it works smoothly.

My code for the location is this.

```
if(navigator.geolocation){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function(position){
    // on success
    loadMap(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
},
function(e){
  // on error
  loadMap(0,0);
}, {maximumAge: 30000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true})
```

The loadMap function passes the arguments so I can create a mapbox map.

I'm using phonegap 6.4.3 and cordova 6.4.0 and compile it to a virtual nexus 5 with Android 7.1

> Error Log

These are the Error messages I get after I clicked on "allow"

```
01-30 18:02:55.545   238   238 E SELinux : avc:  denied  { find } for service=batterymanager scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:battery_service:s0 tclass=service_manager
01-30 18:02:55.662 18458 18502 E libEGL  : validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
01-30 18:02:58.131 18458 18458 E cr_LocationProvider: Caught security exception while registering for location updates from the system. The application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions.
01-30 18:02:58.134 18458 18458 E cr_LocationProvider: Caught security exception while registering for location updates from the system. The application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions.
01-30 18:02:58.136 18458 18458 E cr_LocationProvider: Caught security exception while registering for location updates from the system. The application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions.
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.phonegap.helloworld, PID: 18458
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime: Theme: themes:{com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet=overlay:system}
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.phonegap.helloworld/com.phonegap.helloworld.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext.sendPluginResult(org.apache.cordova.PluginResult)' on a null object reference
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3733)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3776)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext.sendPluginResult(org.apache.cordova.PluginResult)' on a null object reference
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.geolocation.Geolocation.onRequestPermissionResult(Geolocation.java:77)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterfaceImpl.onRequestPermissionResult(CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:214)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(CordovaActivity.java:508)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6582)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6460)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3729)
01-30 18:03:00.577 18458 18458 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
```

Comment: check your logcat and post an error here,so it will be more clear

Comment: This should be the error report report. I also tried it on my phone where I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included this line in your page:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

i was having the same issue, and then realized that i didn't include the cordova.js.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the Geolocation plugin is not yet ready when you using it.
It should be called after the "deviceready" event.

Ref : [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/index.html#ios-quirks)